# Balcon addon error

Tags: add-on

I have download the balcon addon from [here](http://www.blendernation.com/2012/01/25/add-on-balcony-jamb-and-window-generator-scripts/) and its giving an error
[image] Does it support 2.78a version or something else error. How to activate the addon

**new error**
[image]

Comment: Change line 15 to `from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add`  (will at least remove error in q)

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks for replying i have replace that line and activate but when i click shit+A add balkon its giving an new error image attach above

Comment: This is probably an error with the script and should be reported to the addon author

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos there is no email id mention in the script where can report only "author": "SayPRODUCTIONS" written. No website No email id

Comment: This is an old addon circa 2.5 something.  `Mesh.faces` has been replaced with `Mesh.polygons` since ngons.  Replace any instance in code of "mesh.faces" with "mesh.polygons".